# How to load up several handlebars templates at once?

Tags: javascript, loops, handlebars.js

I have setup this page for attaching different handlebars templates into different sections of the page.

```
var source1 = document.getElementById("pref-color-template").innerHTML;
                    var template1 = Handlebars.compile(source1);
                    var output1 = template1(colorData);
                    document.getElementById("pref-color").innerHTML = output1;

                    var source2 = document.getElementById("pref-red-template").innerHTML;
                    var template2 = Handlebars.compile(source2);
                    var output2 = template2(colorData);
                    document.getElementById("pref-red").innerHTML = output2;

                    var source3 = document.getElementById("pref-white-template").innerHTML;
                    var template3 = Handlebars.compile(source3);
                    var output3 = template3(colorData);
                    document.getElementById("pref-white").innerHTML = output3;

                    var source4 = document.getElementById("pref-country-template").innerHTML;
                    var template4 = Handlebars.compile(source4);
                    var output4 = template4(colorData);
                    document.getElementById("pref-country").innerHTML = output4;

                    var source5 = document.getElementById("pref-style-template").innerHTML;
                    var template5 = Handlebars.compile(source5);
                    var output5 = template5(colorData);
                    document.getElementById("pref-style").innerHTML = output5;
```

I'm thinking maybe there is a more efficient way of writing this, like a loop? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var maps = [{
    template: "pref-color-template",
    destination: "pref-color"
}, {
    template: "pref-red-template",
    destination: "pref-red"
}, {
    template: "pref-white-template",
    destination: "pref-white"
}, {
    template: "pref-country-template",
    destination: "pref-country"
}, {
    template: "pref-style-template",
    destination: "pref-style"
}];

var compileTemplate = function (template, destination, data) {
    var templ = Handlebars.compile(document.getElementById(template).innerHTML);
    var output = templ(data);
    document.getElementById(destination).innerHTML = output;
}

for (var i = 0; i < maps.length; i++) {
    compileTemplate(maps[i].template, maps[i].destination, colorData);
}
```

Simple example, but essentially, you would want to store your mappings of template -> destination in an array of objects. I abstracted the actual compiling into a function, but the contents of compileTemplate very well could have been in the for loop directly.

This way, any time you make a change to how you handle something (add different logic) or modify your data, it happens to all template instances.